# Preventing duplicate Environment Variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, environment-variables

I am trying to export an environment variable into the /etc/profile.d. The shell script is as follows

`echo -e "export var1=abc ">>/etc/profile.d/setenv.sh`

The var1 would be a user input and each time i take an input i need to update the environment variable. But the above code results in appending duplicate lines in /etc/profile.d/setenv.sh when we run the above shell script multiple times. Is there a way we can prevent this.

Comment: Try this: `grep -q "export var1=abc" /etc/profile.d/setenv.sh || echo -e "export var1=abc ">>/etc/profile.d/setenv.sh`, append some string to file if the string not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -Ei 's/^(export var1=).*/\1abc/' file
```

or

```sh
perl -i -lpe 's/^export var1=\K.*/abc/' file
```

Those however only modify an existing value. To insert if not found, then we need a little more logic:

```sh
gawk -i inplace '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "="}
    $1 == "export var1" {$2 = "abc"; found = 1}
    {print}
    END {if (!found) print "export var1=abc"}
' file
```